# Is applying Clustering and then Classification good approach to solve multi-categorical classification problems?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, feature-selection, ensemble-learning

Like for following Data Example:

Let's assume I have following T-Shirt size categories:

**Training Data set:**

```
+------+--------+-------+--------+
| Size | Length | Width | Brand  |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
| SS   |      6 |     6 | ABC    |
| S    |    6.2 |   6.2 | ABC    |
| SM   |    6.3 |   6.3 | ABC    |
| M    |      8 |     8 | ABC    |
| MM   |    8.1 |   8.1 | ABC    |
| ML   |    8.2 |   8.2 | ABC    |
| L    |     10 |    10 | ABC    |
| LX   |   10.1 |  10.1 | ABC    |
| X    |   10.2 |  10.2 | ABC    |     
| XL   |   10.5 |  10.5 | ABC    |
| XXL  |   10.7 |  10.7 | ABC    |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
```

I want to reduce the number of Size categories first and then use the output data for making further classification using these newly assigned categories.

Suggestions on approaches really appreciated.

I'm considering:

**First applying Hierarchical Clustering technique like Agglomerative:**

```
+------+--------+-------+--------+
| Size | Length | Width | Brand  |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
| S    |    6.x |   6.x | ABC    |
| M    |    8.x |   8.x | ABC    |
| L    |   10.x |  10.x | ABC    |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
```

And then using this above training data for making further classification of future data:

```
+------+--------+-------+--------+
| Size | Length | Width | Brand  |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
| -    |    6.9 |   6.7 | ABC    |
| -    |    7.3 |   8.1 | ABC    |
| -    |    9.5 |  10.1 | ABC    |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
```

Any suggestion is constructive for me and notes/pointers/tutorials will be very very helpful. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: What exactly do you want to predict, and what problem does your clustering solve?

Comment: Basically I want to reduce the number of categories first which I feel clustering should do effectively. 

And then use these new reduced # of categories for classifying any new data point to one of these new categories. 

Essentially, I want to reduce the granularity of having too many categories.

Comment: Forgot to add you in the reply comment @ArunJose

Answer (score 1):

No.

Don't rely on clustering here. A single outlier might ruin your results.

Use a *human-verified* if-then rule instead. This is a problem difficulty that a human can easily decide,and you get a more intuitive result.

S, M, and L are man made labels.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Though this above sample is just an example. 

My dataset is more abstract then this and unlabeled. To give you more accurate analogy would be to categories user type based on their usage (using clustering). 
And then essentially classify future users along the lines of these categories.